# Let a process use all process power

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, neural-network, cpu

The question is really general, so here is a more detailed information:
I run currently Ubuntu 14.04 and work on a neural network currently. To find optimal parameters I want to train many different parametrized networks and see which one works best.

The network and its training sequence is written in c and I have a 4 core processor. If I run the program it trains each network one after another.

Now the system monitor tells me the programme is using about 25 percent of the total process power. How can I improve that, what is the best way to use all cores equally and 100 percent of my cpu(and gpu?)

Currently I am using the compiling flag `-pthread`, but I guess there are many more possibilities.

Comment: Linking your program with libpthread doesn't mean you're actually using it. If you want to use all the power of your CPU, you'll have to parallelize all the algorithms you have in your ANN. That means, you'll probably have to _rewrite them from scratch_ to make them work utilizing all the 4 cores. These threads will have to communicate somehow and that's a lot of work to make them do this.

Comment: It might be enough to just run four instances of the program at the same time... whether or not that is useful to do would depend on what the program does and how it does it.

Comment: I have one function called `trainNetwork(params[])`, which is called all the times and which works independently. I hoped I could get some easy parallel processing by calling this function multiple times parallel.

Comment: So you'll need to spawn 4 threads (by calling pthread_create() 4 times) and have each thread call trainNetwork() with different arguments.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thank you for your answer, I will try to find more information about that on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the question is general. So is the answer: learn about concurrent programming. Threads, or [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). Especially with OpenMP you might turn your program into a multi-threaded program by adding a single `#pragma` before the right `for` loop.

A different approach could be to have each of the four trainings be performed by a different *process*. The strategy would be to use main's arguments (`argc, argv`) to tell each process what to do. This is easy if there needs to be no communication between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into OpenCL and OpenMP as ways to fully exploit the processing power.  There has been a lot of work on neural nets using OpenCL and CUDA.

These approaches are probably more suited to your neural net.  In addition OpenCL and OpenMP applications can be made to compile to use both CPU and GPU hardware with no significant changes.

OpenCL is a C-like language, and although getting optimal performance from it can be quite tricky, it would, IMO, be well worth your while if neural net stuff is important to you.  In OpenCL you write the bulk of support code in C and invoke a small kernel in OpenCL to do small operations on large volumes of data in parallel.

You may be developing your own software, but I believe that the FANN neural network library did have a version that supported OpenCL.